# 'IUserIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'Identity'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nancy

I'm trying to use the Nancy Stateless Authentication Example but I am getting an `IUserIdentity` error that I don't understand. Here is the code from Nancy's samples

```
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Security;
using Models;

public class SecureModule : NancyModule
{
    //by this time, the api key should have already been pulled out of our querystring
    //and, using the api key, an identity assigned to our NancyContext
    public SecureModule()
    {
        this.RequiresAuthentication();

        Get["secure"] = x =>
        {
            //Context.CurrentUser was set by StatelessAuthentication earlier in the pipeline
            var identity = this.Context.CurrentUser;

            //return the secure information in a json response
            var userModel = new UserModel(identity.Identity.Name);
            return this.Response.AsJson(new
            {
                SecureContent = "here's some secure content that you can only see if you provide a correct apiKey",
                User = userModel
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I am seeing.

> Error CS1061  `IUserIdentity` does not contain a definition for `Identity` and no extension method `Identity` accepting a first argument of type `IUserIdentity` could be found.

When I check `this.Context.CurrentUser` from Nancy's sample project, it says that `currentuser` is from `ClaimsPrincipal`, but when I put the sample code into my project, it says that `currentuser` is from `IUserIdentity`.
Any help will/would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [sample code there is a line in the bootstrapper](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/80d03107c2db076f52f59c8539251861c1200b99/src/Nancy.Demo.Authentication/AuthenticationBootstrapper.cs#L27) that sets the `Context`'s `CurrentUser` to an `IPrinciple`. Do you have a bootstrapper that adjusts what goes into the `CurrentUser` property?

Here's the code they're using in the demo bootstrapper (linked above):

```
ctx.CurrentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(BuildClaims(username), "querystring"));
```